# PEP 442, objects with a __del__() method don’t end up in gc.garbage anymore

Tags: python, garbage-collection

cycles with `__del__` methods are collected. (PEP 442).
but why I got the same result of python2.7 and pyton3.6?
has `a,b,foo,bar` been freed?

```
import gc
import sys


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = None
        print('foo init')

    def __del__(self):
        print("foo del")


class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None
        print('bar init')

    def __del__(self):
        print('bar del')


def collect_and_show_garbage():
    print("Collecting...")
    n = gc.collect()
    print("unreachable objects:", n)


def func():
    foo = Foo()
    bar = Bar()
    foo.bar = bar
    bar.foo = foo


def func2():
    a = [1, 2]
    b = [3, 4]
    a.append(b)
    b.append(a)


func()
func2()
collect_and_show_garbage()
```

> foo init
>   bar init
>   Collecting...
>   foo del
>   bar del
>   unreachable objects: 6

and when i delete `__del__` method, I got the same result

```
import gc
import sys


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = None
        print('foo init')


class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None
        print('bar init')



def collect_and_show_garbage():
    print("Collecting...")
    n = gc.collect()
    print("unreachable objects:", n)


def func():
    foo = Foo()
    bar = Bar()
    foo.bar = bar
    bar.foo = foo


def func2():
    a = [1, 2]
    b = [3, 4]
    a.append(b)
    b.append(a)


func()
func2()
collect_and_show_garbage()
```

> foo init
>   bar init
>   Collecting...
>   unreachable objects: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gc.collect：

> The number of unreachable objects is returned.

gc.garbage:

> A list of objects which the collector found to be unreachable but
>   could not be freed (uncollectable objects).

```
import gc
import sys


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = None
        print('foo init')

    def __del__(self):
        print("foo del")


class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None
        print('bar init')

    def __del__(self):
        print('bar del')


def collect_and_show_garbage():
    print("Collecting...")
    n = gc.collect()
    print("unreachable objects:", n)
    print("uncollectable objects:", gc.garbage)


def func():
    foo = Foo()
    bar = Bar()
    foo.bar = bar
    bar.foo = foo


def func2():
    a = [1, 2]
    b = [3, 4]
    a.append(b)
    b.append(a)


func()
func2()
collect_and_show_garbage()
```

python2.7

> foo init
>   bar init
>   Collecting...
>   ('unreachable objects:', 6)
>   ('uncollectable objects:', [<**main**.Foo object at 0x10cff55d0>,<**main**.Bar object at 0x10cff5650>])

pyhton3.6

> foo init
>   bar init
>   Collecting...
>   foo del
>   bar del
>   unreachable objects: 6
>   uncollectable objects: []